# Увеличение размера кнопки раз в 2 секунды

Tags: javascript

Необходимо чтобы каждые 2 секунды размер кнопки увеличивался на 1.

```
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
    button78.style.width = i + i;
}
```

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали сделать для решения проблемы? Что именно не получилось? Или вы просто хотите, чтобы кто-то написал код за вас?

Comment: Я пробовал сделать функцию, которая будет срабатывать каждые 5 секунд, но почему-то не работает. Поэтому и написал сюда, я только начал разбираться c for.

Comment: Без кода вашей попытке в вопросе, он выглядит как "сделайте за меня". А такие вопрос не очень-то приветствуются сообществом (хотя формально и не запрещены).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, вы делаете первые шаги, поэтому объясню проблемы с вашим кодом:

1. Простой цикл не работает, потому что скрипт выполняется весь сразу, и браузер отрисовывает только конечный результат. Функции задержки в JS нет, среда выполнения предполагает использование функций обратного вызова везде и всюду.
2. Единицы измерения следует указывать явно.

Вот самое простое решение с минимумом магии:

```js
var width = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    button78.style.width = 36 + (width++) + "px";
    if (width >= 28)
        clearInterval(timer);
}, 100);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button78" value="Button"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

- Задержку можно реализовать с помощью функций `setTimeout` и `setInterval`.
- Текущую ширину элемента можно получить с помощью `.offsetWidth`.
- Новое значение ширины (текущее плюс 1, не забывая про `"px"`) можно установить с помощью `.style.width`.

Вариант решения:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var button78 = document.getElementById('button78');
    var maxInc = 28;
    var delay = 100; //2000
    (function incWidth(i) {
        if (i < maxInc) {
            button78.style.width = button78.offsetWidth + 1 + "px";
            setTimeout(function() {
                incWidth(i + 1);
            }, delay);
        }
    })(0);
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button78" value="Button" />
```

Если использование `for` критично, то можно установить в цикле множество `setTimeout` с разным значением задержки:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var button78 = document.getElementById('button78');
    var maxInc = 28;
    var delay = 100; //2000
    function incWidth() {
     button78.style.width = button78.offsetWidth + 1 + "px";
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < maxInc; i++) {
        setTimeout(incWidth, i * delay);
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button78" value="Button" />
```